# Convert nginx conf file to apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to port an conf file from Nginx to Apache. Right now I'm running my website with Nginx, but I would like to use Apache instead of Nginx.

here is the code please help me to convert it into htaccess so that i can use it on apache

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain.mobi www.domain.mobi;
#access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/default.error.log crit;
    root /home/default/public_html/domain;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

#server_name www.domain.mobi;
#rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.mobi/$1 permanent;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        # secure *.php files
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

rewrite ^/(.*)/page-([0-9]+)$ /?load=$1/page-$2 last;
rewrite ^/newest$ /?load=newest last;
rewrite ^/top-rated$ /?load=top-rated last;
rewrite ^/most-viewed$ /?load=most-viewed last;
rewrite ^/categories$ /?load=categories last;
rewrite ^/dmca$ /?load=dmca last;
rewrite ^/privacy$ /?load=privacy last;
rewrite ^/help$ /?load=help last;
 rewrite ^/(.*).html$ /?load=$1.html last;
rewrite ^/favorites/add-([0-9]+)$ / redirect;
rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /?load=search/$1 last;
rewrite ^/search$ /search.php last;
rewrite ^/(.*).html/download$ /download.php?file=$1 last;

rewrite ^/keyword$ /?load=keyword last;
rewrite ^/keyword$ /?load=keyword last; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.